# $http promise not able to read data from callback

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a factory with $http. In a browser I check the network tab and I see that the call has come trough and that the data is there but for some reason this code:

```
$scope.naloziPodatke = function () {
    if (typeof $scope.Obdobje_do === 'undefined' || typeof $scope.Obdobje_do === 'undefined') {
        alert("Napaka. Obdobje ni nastavljeno.");
    } else {
        getData.gData($scope.Obdobje_od.toLocaleDateString("en-US"), $scope.Obdobje_do.toLocaleDateString("en-US")).success(function (d) {
            console.log(d); $scope.data = d;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.d.length; i++) {
                    var virTasks = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.data.d.SeznamVirov.length; j++) {
                        virTasks.push({ id: $scope.data.d[i].SeznamVirov[j].Id, subject: "", from: $scope.data.d[i].SeznamVirov[j].ObdobjeOd, to: $scope.data.d[i].SeznamVirov[j].ObdobjeDo, color: $scope.barve[colorCount], data: { id: $scope.data.d[i].SeznamVirov[j].Vir } });
                    }
                    $scope.dasData.push({
                        id: $scope.data.d[i].Id, name: $scope.data.d[i].Naziv, tasks: virTasks
                    });
                    if (colorCount + 1 === barve.length) {
                        colorCount = 0;
                    } else {
                        colorCount++;
                    }
                }
                console.log($scope.dasData);
        });
    }
}
```

Returns an error: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined.

d should be an array that .net serializer makes. It's there, browser sees it but angular does not.

You will notice that i have a console.log(d); before the for loop starts and this is the screenshot (dont get how console.log gets the data but the for loop doesnt (it's the same if i try to loop trough d or if i'm saving it's reference into $scope.data):

[image: error]

The service is very simple:

```
hermesGantt.factory('getData', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        gData: function (obdOd, obdDo) {
            return $http({ method: 'POST', url: 'index.aspx/Filtercasvir', data: { 'odObd': obdOd, 'doObd': obdDo } });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to access `d.data`? responses from `$http` promises are usually objects with response returned as `data` property

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible what you have write, data.d.something. maybe it's data[index].d[index] etc.. etc.. to let you know it, do the console.log(data) so you can see the entire response fields

## EDIT

seeing your image it's clear what i have said before, d is a **field** that has as a value an **array**. To access at any value you need to put the index of the elements value in the d field. take a look at the documentation for the json array, it is really use full in angularjs.

Comment: Check this picture out: http://i.imgur.com/o5sEWHD.png

This is my data. It loads on google, i'm using .success and doing for loops after I'm sure i get the data. I'm not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in second inner loop. Correct is:

```
for (var j = 0; j < $scope.data.d[i].SeznamVirov.length; j++) ...
```